# Algebraic relations between trigonometric numbers

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, transcendental-numbers

Given $n\in2\Bbb N$, what is precise algebraic relation between $cos\frac{\pi}{n-1}$,$cos\frac{\pi}{n+1}$?

Both numbers are algebraic, which implies there should be an algebraic relation between them. What is this precise relation?

Is this relation $$\frac{T_{n-1}\big(cos\frac{\pi}{n^2-1}\big)}{T_{n+1}\big(cos\frac{\pi}{n^2-1}\big)}=\frac{cos\frac{\pi}{n+1}}{cos\frac{\pi}{n-1}}$$ where $T_n(x)$ is Tchebyshev polynomial of first kind?

Answer (score 1):

These are algebraic numbers, not transcendental, so there are certainly algebraic relations involving them.  For example, $T_n(\cos(\pi/n)) = T_m(\cos(\pi/m)) = -1$ where $T_m$ and $T_n$ are Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind.

Comment: I have title as trigonometric numbers. I am looking at better relations?

Comment: If $m \mid n$ then $T_{n/m}(\cos(\pi/n)) = \cos(\pi/m)$.

Comment: More generally, if $d = \gcd(m,n)$, then $T_{n/d}(\cos(\pi/n)) = T_{m/d}(\cos(\pi/m))$.

Comment: As to the new question, in general $\cos(\pi/(n+1))$ will not be in the field generated by $\cos(\pi/(n-1))$ over the rationals, so there is no such construction.

Comment: Isn't it true there is always an algebraic relation between two algebraic numbers?

Comment: Is there a reference for the Chebyshev identity? So it seems that $$T_{n-1}\big(cos(\frac{\pi}{n^2-1})\big)=cos(\frac{\pi}{n+1})$$
$$T_{n+1}\big(cos(\frac{\pi}{n^2-1})\big)=cos(\frac{\pi}{n-1})$$

Comment: No, $T_n(\cos(x)) = \cos(nx)$.  See e.g. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html

Comment: I just translated your second comment. $m=n+1$ and $n$ replaced by $n^2-1$ gives $(n^2-1)/(n+1)=n-1$. It seems $T_n(cos(\pi/n))=cos(\pi)$ holds. $m|n\implies T_{n/m}(cos(\pi/n))=cos(\pi/m)$ produces these identities.

Comment: Your second identity seems wrong. What happens if $d=gcd(m,n)=1$?

Comment: If $d = 1$ it says $T_n(\cos(\pi/n))=T_m(\cos(\pi/m)$.

Comment: thats right they value $-1$.